# What is the Azure product lifetime

Tags: azure

If I build application based o Azure today, is there some guarantee by Microsoft that Azure will be still supported and living after 15 years? What is the product lifetime of Azure? What is the guarantee that I don't have additional cost of migrating to the new azure API new feature every few years?

Comment: Aside from this being off-topic (as it's not a programming question): Regardless of any answers posted here, there's no accurate answer you'll receive. There's simply no way to tell what will or won't be supported in 15 years. There's no way to know the product lifetime of Azure. Nothing but speculation. Yet you marked an answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the service of Azure you want to use. Overall Microsoft always informs you about changes. You always get informat month before a service will be changed or dropped. Take a look at [Microsoft Azure Cloud Lifecycle FAQ](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle#gp/azure-cloud-lifecycle-faq).

It also depends if you want to use the PaaS, IaaS or SaaS elements. No SaaS host provides you for years the same version. Software has always a lifecycle.

In Azure you pay like on other platforms just for your usage. If you migrate from VM 1 to VM 2 and both are running for 3 days in parallel, then you have to pay that. But you do not have any addition fee just to use the newest service.

---

From provided link I can cite for guest OS:

**When will a Guest OS family be retired?**

> In the future whenever a new Guest OS family is introduced, Microsoft
>   Azure will provide 12 months of notice to retire the oldest Guest OS
>   family from the list of supported OS families.

**What can I expect after the 12 months of notification period?**

*At the end of the 12 month notification period, Microsoft Azure will stop providing the latest/patched version for a retired OS family. The cloud services using the retired OS family will be unsupported and will be stopped.*

For azure cloud services, it is similar.

Answer (score 3):

I would be exceptionally surprised if Azure in its current state had any resemblance to Azure in 15 years time.

For instance, Amazon Web services launched with nothing but S3 only ten years ago. It is hardly recognizable from that form today. Although as a basic service S3 is mostly identical.

Cloud services are a very rapidly growing and developing solution. They all need to be constantly moving to keep up with technology. By moving to Azure you accept that there will be a migration plan as solutions evolve.

Basic services like compute, storage and networking will likely largely stay the same. The APIs that you access them with will almost certainly change, but the underlying ability to network and compute will remain (maybe with the introduction of some Quantum compute cores too ;) )

However the drive across cloud platforms is towards standardisation and automation. For instance you can create a Docker container solution that will be able to run on ANY cloud service unchanged. This theme will likely continue for the foreseeable future.

Cloud services will change drastically over the next 15 years, they will become leaner, easier to maintain and simpler to deploy.